# Why a List<type> absorbs not-type element in compilation and execution time?

Tags: java, exception, generics, types, casting

I have this demo, which I dont need a particular solution with a redrawn architecture, but just understanding why behaves like that and any thing I am missing for avoiding it. I am wondering why:

- Compiler allows the insertion of an element that its not the type of the list into the list
- The ClassCast exception is thrown when we try to get the element instead of when pushing it

  ```
  import Test.*; //Inner classes
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class Test<E extends Object> {

      private List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
      public Test() {}

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Test<String> a = new Test<String>();
          a.addElement(new String());
          a.addElement(new Integer(0)); // No complain in comp/run-time, I dont understand why CastException is not thrown here
          String class1 = a.getElement(0); 
          String class2 = a.getElement(1); //No complain in comp but ClassCastException: Integer cannot be cast to String
          //Integer class3 = a.getElement(1); //Compilation error
      }

      public void addElement (Object node) { list.add((E) node); } //No complain in comp/run-time
      public E getElement(int index)       { return list.get(index); }
  }
  ```

What could be a solution? Notice the line addElement where I need to pass a SuperClass, instead of type E. This is needed for my architecture, this is just a simple mock demo. But anyway the casting to type E should act as desired and throw a CastExeption in runtime, should not?

Comment: Casting to generic types never throws a `ClassCastException` because of type erasure.  (Except if the type has a concrete upper bound, but then it only checks against that upper bound.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `(E) node` doesn't do run-time type check due to type erasure. All the information about generic types is lost after compilation.

Java compiler should warn you about it:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to E
```

You can do this check manually by using reference to [java.lang.Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

```
private Class<E> clazz;

public Test(Class clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public void addElement (Object node) {
    list.add(clazz.cast(node));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test<String> test = new Test(String.class);
    test.addElement("test");
    test.addElement(Integer.intValue(10));
}
```

Comment: But isnt (E) myObj acting in my case like (String) myObj? Why is it working, do u mean that list is not absorbing at all any type, so from the moment I make the cast, this list is an implicit List<Object> ? If its like that I dont understand why...

Comment: @user1352530 Read about "type erasure" and "unchecked cast" warning. I'm sure you will be able to find better explanation.

Comment: I am doing it now. My basis error is thinking that you can cast to a type and it works as a normal casting.

Answer (score 5):

Your addElement method is not using generics properly to allow for compile-time error catching. It should be:

```
public void addElement(E node) {
  list.add(node);
}
```

Once you use Object cast and cast it to E, you lose compile-time type checking benefits. That's why we use generics in the first place, to avoid using Object variables and avoid casting.

Note that at run time the List is simply a List of Object due to generic type erasure, so the first cast, when you're placing the object into the list, doesn't even occur. But when you extract the item from the list and need to assign it to concrete type variable a behinds the scene cast does occur, and this causes your exception to be thrown.

Comment: @Pshemo: yes, you are correct. Generics will take care of that for us. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: I said it at the end. This line cannot be touched for external reasons. Anyway, why it should not work, I can pass an Object and try to cast it to either Integer or String (type E)!

Comment: @user1352530: once you cast, you lose compile-time type checking benefits. That's why we use generics in the first place, to avoid using `Object` variables and avoid casting.

Comment: You don't need to cast to (E) because you've already specified in the method signature that the provided object needs to be of type E.

Comment: Yes but thats only if I was allowed to rewrite the method expecting E instead of Object. but I cannot.

Comment: @user1352530: then you will lose the benefits of compile-time generic type checking.

Comment: @user1352530: At run time the List is simply a List of Object due to generic type erasure, so the first cast doesn't even occur. But when you extract the item from the list a behinds the scene cast *does* occur and causes your exception.

Comment: @user1352530: It's best to think of generics as compile-time _annotations._  They're not actually checked at runtime.