# Cleanest way to fix this castings behavior

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, downcast

Imagine I have a list with 50 different type of a certain subclasses of Node which I expect to be the same type or get a ClassException if not. I have a method which receives this list and a node holding and expeting a certain type

I would like to do something like this:

```
public <E extends Node> receive(List<Node> list, Node<E extends Node> node){
    for (Node element : list ){
         node.addElement((E) element); //Type erasure, if you put wrong node no CastException in Runtime 
    }
}
```

but avoid doing this:

```
public <E extends Node> receive(List<Node> list, Node<E extends Node> node){
    for (Node element : list ){
         if      (element instanceof SubNode1) node.addElement((Subnode1) element); 
         else if (element instanceof SubNode2) node.addElement((Subnode2) element);
         //(...)
         else if (element instanceof SubNode50) node.addElement((Subnode50) element);
    }
}
```

If I cannot cast to generic it would be great doing something like this:

```
public <E extends Node> receive(List<Node> list, Node<E extends Node> node){
    for (Node element : list ){
         node.addElement(element.autoDowncastToSubClassOf("Node"));
    }
}
```

All this options are taking into account node.addElement(E node), so is expecting E. I thought of changing this for accepting any kind of Node and make the cast. But then it happens this: [Why a List<type> absorbs not-type element in compilation and execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594823/why-a-listtype-absorbs-not-type-element-in-compilation-and-execution-time)

Should I discard this second approach?

Comment: Why do  you feel  you must cast when you add the node to the list? The casting adds nothing whatsoever as it does not change the type of the underlying object being added to the tree. It potentially changes the type of the parameter holding the object, but again the underlying object is unchanged, and once added to the list tree, the cast is as if it never occurred since the parameter is gone.

Comment: I dont add the node to the list. I have a list of nodes, because a external code, but the thig is this list is expected to be populated with a Subnode type E, which should throw some exception soon if its not like this

Comment: But casting will not solve this.

Comment: The instanceof example (2nd one) works as expected. But I need some mechanism for doing it dynamical

Comment: So you're trying to generate and catch a runtime exception here? Or are you simply trying to avoid adding a node to the root node if your node type isn't 1 to 50?

Comment: I am trying to dynamically infer the subclass type to pass it and expect some Cast exception if this subclass is not the type E addElements expects

Comment: Are you telling us that yoiu have 50 overloaded `getElement` methods? If yes, nothing can solve it for you except reflection.

Comment: I dont understand the comment, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no answers for this and the clue is given here after a lot of research and focusing the topic in different ways, I point to the expected solution:

[How can I downcast to class' type E or at least make it in a safe way without warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610421/how-can-i-downcast-to-class-type-e-or-at-least-make-it-in-a-safe-way-without-wa)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a particular class of Node always takes its own class of node as elements,

Supposed you have a class or interface like:

```
class Node<E> {
    public void addSubElement(E node) { ... }
}
```

and then your Node classes are all like this:

```
class Subnode1 extends Node<Subnode1>
```

Then you can perhaps write your method like this:

```
public <E extends Node<E>> receive(List<Node<?>> list, E node){
    for (Node<?> element : list) {
         node.addElement(node.getClass().cast(element));
    }
}
```