# How can I downcast to class' type E or at least make it in a safe way without warnings?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, downcast

I have super abstract class Node and 50 types of subclasses SubNode.

I have a generic Class <E extends Node> which has a private var List<E> and a method which unfortunately has to accept superclass Node ALWAYS, cannot move it to just E:

```
 public void addSubElement (Node node){ 
        if (node instanceOf E) subElements.add((E)node); 
        else //Doing extra steps for occasional non-E nodes like discarding them silently without CastException; 
 }
```

Any solution (Reflection?) able to compile without warnings, throwing a CastException instead of adding any object due to type erasure??...

I don´t want to have to write same function for any type of subclass:

```
 public void addSubElement (Node node){                             
        if (node instanceOf SubNode1) subElements.add((SubNode1)node); 
        if (node instanceOf SubNode2) subElements.add((SubNode2)node); 
        //if (node instanceOf SubNode50....
 }
```

It would be so nice having a method like.

```
public void addSubElement (Node node){ 
        subElements.add((E)node.autoCastToSubClassOfAbstract("Node")); //Should throw CastException if non-E
 }
```

or

```
 public void addSubElement (Node node){ 
        subElements.add(node.autoCastTo("E")); //Should throw CastException if non-E
 }
```

Comment: So your `add` method is `add(Object)`? And why don't you just call it by `subElements.add(node)`?

Comment: Because subElements.add() expects an E instance, so if I send an Object it fails. .Ok I changed Object -> Integer/String for Node->SubNode1...50 which are easier to not see as stupid

Comment: You are performing a fundamentally unsafe operation so you're obviously going to get a warning. If you want to compile without warnings, add `@SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: this is a continuation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601200/cleanest-way-to-fix-this-castings-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: FINAL ANSWER FROM ALL OTHER ANSWERS:**

I was hesitating if accepting titofb answer, beause he is the one who appointed the good way. But I think it is enough targeted on y problem that  should acept my own (for very 1st time), for the benefit of others who read it. Thanks to all!

Abstract Node class implements this:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected final Class<E> getChildType(){
        return (Class<E>)(((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]); 
    }
```

So any Subnode has always an available method which returns his own Type E from definition
SubnodeN extends Node<SubNodeX> (SubnodeX = N in Node<E>). That means that we can do that in any node:

```
 public void addSubElement (Node<?> node){ 
      Class<E> expectedChildType = getChildType();
      if (expectedChildType.isAssignableFrom(node.getClass())){//if node instanceOf E
         subElements.add(expectedChildType.cast(node)); 
      }
      else throw new ClassCastException("A non-expected child was intended to add to this "+this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" element");
 }
```

And then here it is the magic. This is the default behavior. It warns you if some child was not expected, but you can override this method for any subnode for handling special cases:

```
 @Override
 public void addSubElement (Node<?> node){ 
      if (node instanceOf SubNode34) {/* Yes, our current subnode does not expect all elements intended to be added as E type nodes, we can silently discard or do whatever */}
      else super.addSubElement(node) //Parents default behavior
 }
```

Comment: You might want to move the handling of "is not of expected type" to a `protected` method. That way, the handling for the "correct" case (node type == expected type) can be reused.

Answer (score 2):

If you are *forced* somehow to have a

```
public void addSubElement (Node node);
```

then your only option is to use

```
public void addSubElement (Node node){ 
    subElements.add((E)node); 
}
```

There is no way to achieve this without getting a warning (which you of course can suppress).

This is fine as long as you are the only one using this method, you can just ignore the warning as long as you make sure to always call it with the correct argument.

Comment: This is just a Demo. A Node of sometype could expect a child subnode of any type and decide what to do on it. If its E type it could be added to his natural list, but if not, it could be used anyway. You have to think the class is generic, that means that if I want to acept any node and cast it to E I have to do it for any Class<E>

Comment: Commenting the answer, I need to cast somewhat so I receive a CastException before I introduce a bad element in list.

Comment: @user1352530: That isn't possible. It seems like a flaw in the design if `Subnode`s of one kind can find their way into a class handling another kind of `Subnode`.

Comment: exatly, but just in the inner list. The idea is the Node class accepts any Node as subElement (child), and puts it by default in his expected list. If a node its not of type E, then a CastException is thrown. But node is abstract so if we have a Subnode extending node, we could override this addElement method changing the default and putting an additional extra step for handling Node which are not E for discarding them silently or doing other operations other than adding to the main list

Comment: @user1352530: If subElements can be of any `Node` subType, then why is the type `List<E>` and not `List<Node>`? I'm sorry, but I think you have lost me here.

Comment: Because the list can only be populated with E. That does not mean that addElements do only accept Subnodes of type E (default behavior: put in list), but also nodes of other type for discarding without a CastException, do extra things but never put them in the list

Comment: Remember with your solution, any SubNode type gets added to the list beause of type erasure, so not handling a CastException

Answer (score 2):

You have a flaw in your design. Either the signature of the method should be:

```
public void addSubElement (E node)
```

or `subElements` should be of type `List<Node>` instead `List<E>`.

Let's say your class is `NodeList<E extends Node>`, and then you create an instance:

```
NodeList<SubNode1> nl = new NodeList<SubNode1>();
```

Then the list will only accept instances of `SubNode1`, so you wouldn't be able to do

```
nl.addSubElement(subNode2Instance)
```

Update:

The only workaround that I found is this:

```
private static class G<E extends NodeB> {

    private E templateObject;

    private List<E> subElements = new ArrayList<E>();

    public G(E templateObject) {
        this.templateObject = templateObject;
    }

    public void addSubElement (NodeB node) {
        if (templateObject.getClass().isAssignableFrom(node.getClass())) {
            subElements.add((E) node);
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I know, but I must parse any Node, because I can need extra actions when very ocasionally, child Node is not the expected E which I always have to put in the list.

Comment: I am asking any reflection way of doing it, I know it seems a bad idea, but I need it to make it work in order to assess that, as I donßt think so

Comment: If you need it to work like that, just use @Keppil's solution. It will throw ClassCastException when the types won't match.

Comment: No. Here comes the problem. Because of type erasure, the list adds any element if I do that, even if node is not of type E.

Comment: I think you're wrong, it will throw ClassCastException. The type erasure will replace E with the subclass of node that you use when instantiating the class.

Comment: Answering the edit. Node<E> has List<E>, it has no sense to me rewrite for any of the 50 nodes and the forthcomers which extend abstract Node<E>, the List<E> to List<Subnode1>, List<Subnode2..>. Its neither scalable if u keep changing nodes. A node<E> eypets E everywhere, its just that it can have non-E childs in which case we need to check for not putting in the list. Perhaps through reflection with Class<E> and downcasting or something?

Comment: I am not wrong, from yesterday -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594823/why-a-listtype-absorbs-not-type-element-in-compilation-and-execution-time :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated my answer with a workaround. I know it's not nice, but maybe it will help you somehow.

Comment: This sems a very very useful answer to me for the time being, I try to modify to my particular case and give feedback

Answer (score 1):

When using generics, there are corner cases where you can't write valid code without suppressing warnings.

The pure OO approach for your problem would be to write on `addSubElement()` method for each type. That would give you one method per type in each type (N*N). You could add the special cases in the respective types.

Obviously for any significant number of different types (say more than three), the number of methods quickly explodes and you will find yourself in a situation where you have to cut&paste a lot of code.

Even if you need only to write a few of them and delegate most of the work to a generic `addSubElement(Node)` method, it would still create a technical debt because you'd need to write X methods for each new type.

So for your corner case, there is probably no way around `instanceof` and `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

**[EDIT]**

You could define an interface `INode` which `Node` has to implement. Your class could then look like this:

```
public Node<E,N extends INode> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void addSubElement(N n) { ... }
}
```

This pattern would allow you to either restrict the possible types of nodes which this implementation accepts or use `Node` for `N` for something that accepts anything and where you do special handling in the method.

The advantage here is that you could get compile time errors when you pass a type to an implementation which can't handle it. But you would still need a cast in the method and to suppress the warning.

Comment: But you mean having an addSubElement(N n) along with the addSubElement(E n) ? Because I tried that and it says they are the same because of type erasure!

Comment: No, just one `addSubElement(N n)` The trick is that you define *two* independent generic types so you can control what your single method accepts.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. Nice idea too! I will try whih scenario fits better, both answers are great