# Confusion with type erasure rule in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have been into Generics for an hour, I have certain doubts. Lets say I have a class like this :

```
class Pair<T>
{
       public T getFirst() { return first; }
}
```

Basically my book say this :

> **Type erasure:** The type variables are erased and replaced by their bounding types (or
>   Object for variables without bounds.)

So according to my book statement the code in JVM should look like  :

```
 class Pair
    {
           public Object getFirst() { return first; }
    }
```

Now if I do :

```
   Pair<String> pair = new Pair<>(); //I use Java 7 diamond syntax here.
   pair.getFirst()
```

Is that again my code need to convert from `Object` to `String` in return type of `getFirst`?

Now conisder :

```
ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
```

The same book say's (with respect to the above code is) :

```
....the files contain array of Strings.
```

I'm very much confused about the type erasure rule with the above example of `ArrayList`. In this case how come `files` array know that it has `String` array? (which is contradicting to type erasure rule)

#### Edit:

In order to see the resulting code of `Pair`(that is how type erasure have taken place), how can I use `javap` tool here?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: At runtime, the files array doesn't _know_ it contains Strings, but the compiler knows at compile time.

Comment: @MattR seeing as it knows at compile-time, it must know at runtime. Information is not lost between the two

Comment: The compiler can be tricked into accepting a different type into an array, and you'll have an exception only when you try to get the element from the array. Check this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11610421/1384984

Comment: @James the type is erased so call that "lost" if you like :-) It's an Array of Objects, but it's true that exceptions will be thrown if it doesn't contain Strings at runtime

Comment: "The compiler can be tricked into accepting a different type into an array" <-- I was not aware of this, having never tried to do so. I don't think most sane people do >.< I shall remember this for future questions on type erasure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion comes from what the compiler does and what the JVM does.

```
Pair<String> pair = new Pair<>(); //I use Java 7 diamond syntax here.
String first = pair.getFirst();
```

is equivalent in the JVM to

```
Pair pair = new Pair(); 
String first = (String) pair.getFirst();
```

In the case of Map.get()

```
Map<Key, Value> map = ...
Value value = map.get(key);
```

is in the JVM

```
Map map = ...
Value value = (Value) map.get(key);
```

> Is that again my code need to convert from Object to String in return type of getFirst?

No conversion occurs. The object is not altered. All that happens is there might be a cast check of the reference.

> In order to see the resulting code of Pair(that is how type erasure have taken place), how can I use javap tool here?

Use `javap -c -classpath . ClassUsingPair`

Comment: So in your 1st code example `pair.getFirst();` should return `String` type, then why there is a cast required?

Comment: `pair.getFirst()` always returns an Object AFTER type erasure. You have to think about the differences in how the compiler compiles the code and how the JVM sees the byte code.

Comment: Oh! I understood. My last question is people say type casting is always difficult. But under the hood generic does the same. Isn't that bad?

Comment: Its not quite the same. There is a cast for returned values.  It adds boilerplate code for you, you might otherwise have to write which is better.

Comment: Type casting is a pain to get right and if this means the compiler can do most of the work for you and gets it right at compile time instead of throwing a runtime exception, that's an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `Erasure` is a **process in which Compiler removes the** `Type parameter` and `Type arguments` from during the compilation from Class and Method, Variables etc...

**2.** Box becomes Box, this is called **raw-type**, **Raw-type is one where the generic class or interface name will be without type argument.**

**3.** So during run-time one won't find the Generics...**its mainly done to make the code that didn't used generics to run without any problem**, mainly those that were written before Generics came into existence.

**4.** Generic Class won't be instantiated, cause it needs its constructor to be initiated, and that wont happen as the original Type parameter wont be there during the Runtime.